# TableView Inside tableView Cell In swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

In this image I have two section in this table view . In the second section there is a tableview inside the cell. i want to fetch the textfield data of the “inner table view” in the current class. How to do this? followings are the code for my tableview cell .I want to fetch "InerTableViewCell1" data in "outerTableView". How to do this?

[image]

```
//MARK- UITableViewDataSource
extension outerTableView: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 1
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell1", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell1
            
            return cell1!
        }
        else{
            
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell2
            cell2!.innerTableView.reloadData()
            return cell2!
            
        }
    }
```

```
class TableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK- IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var innerTableView: UITableView!
    
    //MARK- Properties
    var rowNumber = 1
    
    //MARK- Lifecycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        innerTableView.dataSource = self
        innerTableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

//MARK- UITableViewDataSource
extension TableViewCell2: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("row number is \(rowNumber)")
        return rowNumber
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InerTableViewCell1", for: indexPath) as? InerTableViewCell1
        return cell!
    }
    }
}
```

```
class InerTableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK- IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var firstUserNameTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstAdressTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var secondUserNameTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var secondAdressTextField: UITextField!
    
    //MARK- Lifecycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Nested table views ***rarely*** work without problems. You'd probably be better off using a cell with a `UIStackView` and adding your labels and text fields as arranged subviews.